# Offline dictionary for IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, dictionary, cpu-word

I am using [Offline Dictionary](http://www.lexicontext.com/) for my word game application, It's nice product for offline dictionary. Today I ran into a situation, I need a random word which is starting with letter "A" and contains 4 letters only. I have tried  below code to get my required criteria but this wont help much because many times my criteria fails, Which leads to application struck by finding a word.

```
Lexicontext *dictionary = [Lexicontext sharedDictionary];
NSString *word = [dictionary randomWord];
```

Same failure with this code too

```
Lexicontext *dictionary = [Lexicontext sharedDictionary];
NSDictionary *words = [dictionary wordsWithPrefix:@"A"];
```

With the words dictionary I am checking my criteria. This gives me accurate output but only the problem I found here is, getting the **words** dict taking long time on the device(~13sec).

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way to get a word by passing start letter and number of characters that word needs to be?
2. Anybody suggest me some more offline dictionaries for IOS.

Answer (score 0):

> NSString *word = [dictionary randomWord];

returns a random word from the dictionary without any restrictions.

On the other hand running

> NSDictionary *words = [dictionary wordsWithPrefix:@"A"];

would return a result of about 1800 Adjectives, 400 Adverbs, 500 Verbs... and will probably be too slow :)

Such a search does not return a result for nouns and a warning is printed to the log. It is therefore advisable to constrain your searches to prevent such cases. If you must, you can so multiple two-letter prefix searches ('aa', 'ab', 'ac', ...) in advance and cache the results.